# make xaxis datalabels have same color like bar Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

i try to make each datalabels Xaxis to have the same color like bar's color

is there any way to make it match?

heres the code

```
var colors = ['#76daff','#b9f','#99ffa6','#ffc312'];
xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      labels: {
        useHTML : true,
        formatter: function () {
             return '<div class="myToolTip" style="color:'+colors+'">'+this.value+'</div>';
        },
      }
    },
```

heres the [link for full code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PervqQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you're filling a representation of the complete `colors` array into your style definition. This results in the following:

```
style="color:#76daff,#b9f,#99ffa6,#ffc312"
```

Which obviously is not the desired behavior.

But your `formatter` function is able to get information about its context (in this case the corresponding data point) by using `this` as already shown by using `this.value` to display the correct value. `this` additional has a `this.pos` property that contains an index for the current data point. (Thankfully the index starts counting with 0 as every programmer would do)

So by slightly adapting your code, you get the current matching color instead of the complete array:

```
formatter: function () {
  return '<div class="myToolTip" style="color:'+colors[this.pos]+'">'+this.value+'</div>';
}
```

But as another safeguard, you could either replicate the highcharts behavior when fewer colors than values are given (at the end of your color array, you simply start all over again by using modulo):

```
formatter: function () {
  return '<div class="myToolTip" style="color:'+colors[this.pos % color.length]+'">'+this.value+'</div>';
}
```

**Edit:** I [updated your codepen](https://codepen.io/loxos-the-vuer/pen/RyXNwN) to show you a working example. I also used at standard formatString to also style the actual value accordingly.

Comment: still i find it undefined sir. when i try to console this.pos the result is undefined.

Comment: @gerryoftrivia i see the background color working in your codepen right now. But I'm not sure what kind of images you're trying to load now...

Comment: @gerryoftrivia I added a codepen top show you the working example. Feel free to ask another question for further unclarities.

Comment: i see, my highchart js version's is 5.0.7. when i change the version from your codepen, it doesnt work. hahahaha thank you sir for your help.